# Entity Framework self referencing table. Error : 'multiple entities with the same key' when SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class `Dept` that has an `Employee` member. I would like to have a `Dept` with an employee - `Boss`. `Boss` has a self referencing employee `Pleb`. When I try to save the dept and employees as a graph to the database I get an error.

How can I configure this to allow me save it?

If I just save the employee `Boss` using `context.Employee.Add(boss)`, both employees are persisted to the database. Linking it to the dept and saving the dept fails. It also works if I remove `Pleb` from the `Boss`.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Employee Parent { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Dept Dept { get; set; }
}

public class Dept
{
    public int DeptId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Employee Boss { get; set; }
}

/* Context class code below */
public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
public DbSet<Dept> Dept { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Dept>()
            .HasKey(e => e.DeptId)
            .HasOptional(e => e.Boss)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Dept);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasKey(e => e.EmployeeId)
            .HasOptional(e => e.Parent)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentId);
}

public class Tests
{
    public void SelfRefTest()
    {
        using (AvertContext context = new AvertContext())
        {
            Dept dept = new Dept {Name = "Sales"};

            Employee pleb = new Employee { Name = "Pleb in the dept" };
            Employee boss = new Employee { Name = "Boss in the dept" };

            boss.Parent = pleb;
            dept.Boss = boss;

            context.Dept.Add(dept);
            context.SaveChanges(); // This is where the error occurs.
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key.
>
> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key.

Comment: You may need to save the employees `context.Employee.Add(pleb)`, `context.Employee.Add(boss)`.

Comment: EF should work out the addition of the employees through the dept without any trouble if they are mapped correctly, which they do look to be. I didn't see any Identity definition nor PKs being set in the example so I suspect that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you set up the entities with Identity as the DatabaseGeneratedOption. Without that it would be trying to insert both employee records with EmployeeId = 0.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
        .HasKey(e => e.EmployeeId)
        .Property(e => e.EmployeeId)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
        .HasOptional(e => e.Parent)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentId);
```

Same would go for the PKs of any entity with an identity/sequence value. (Applies to GUID PKs using defaults of NewId/NewSequentialId as well)

Comment: I'm using EF V6.2 and it doesn't appear to have HasProperty; do you know what version that property is in?

Comment: Typo... It should have been `.Property(...)`. It's been a while since I've used modelBuilder and pulling that from memory. :)

Comment: I tried that but had to make a little amendment and had to split it across to statements but I'm still getting the same error. He is what I changed it to:
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .HasKey(e => e.EmployeeId)            
                .HasOptional(e => e.Parent)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .Property(e => e.EmployeeId)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

Comment: Hmm, is this code-first or database-first? (is there an existing DB schema?) If you check the database itself, does it show that the EmployeeID is an identity column?  If you insert just the one row without the boss reference, what ID gets inserted for the new employee?